# Is there an homeomorphism between $D^2$ and $S^1\times I$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I would to like to know if there is an homeomorphism between the unit disk $D^2$ and $S^1\times I$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle. If I prove this homeomorphism I will be able to solve a question related which I'm struggling with.

Thanks

Comment: But! $D^2\setminus\{0\}$ *is* homeomorphic to $S^1\times (0,1]$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No they are not: $S^1 \times I$ is a cylinder and is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. (To see this, stamp on it harshly once with your left foot.)

But $S^1$ is not homotopy equivalent to $D^2$ hence also not homeomorphic to $D^2$. (Every homeomorphism is also a homotopy equivalence.)

Comment: See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=O319SgIPsJ8C&lpg=PA15&ots=EWUOFOPhHQ&dq=cylinder%20is%20homotopy%20equivalent%20to%20S%5E1&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false), also.

Comment: Can I say $S^1\times I/S^1\times \{1\}$ is homeomorphic to D^2?

Comment: @user42912 Yes, you can!

Comment: @user42912 An easy way to do so is to send the point $(\theta, x)$ ( in product coordinates) to the point $(\theta, 1-x)$ (in polar coordinates).

Comment: An interesting follow-up question would be what happens if you stamp on $S^1\times I$ more than once. And what happens if you use your right foot? Is there a chirality phenomenon?

Comment: @MihaHabič Well, I am not sure whether you are taking up the train of humorous writing or whether you are complaining about it. If the latter I will gladly edit my answer. If the former: once you stamped it's infinitely thin and flat hence cannot be compressed any more and hence nothing happens. As for the right foot: I am left-footed so I cannot try.

Answer (score 8):

No, they are not: $D^2$ is [contractible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space), and $S^1\times I$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

No, use fundamental groups and their invariance under homotopy equivalences:

$S^1\times I\sim S^1$ then $\pi_1(S^1\times I)\simeq\pi_1(S^1)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$

$D^2\sim\{p\}$ then $\pi_1(D^2)\simeq\pi_1(\{p\})\simeq\{1\}$

And clearly, $\{1\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic groups